# Точка входа в процедуру CancelIoEx не найдена в KERNEL32.dll

Tags: kernel

> Точка входа в процедуру CancelIoEx не найдена в библиотеке DLL KERNEL32.dll.

(Qt). Как исправить ?

Comment: Нельзя исправить не видя кода, не зная платформы и ЯП.

Answer (score 2):

Эта функция доступна начиная с Windows Vista. Вероятно у вас Windows XP.

Источник: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363792(v=vs.85).aspx